# php simple concatenation problem

Tags: php, string, concatenation, title

Here is a code sample of PHP function which prints HTML links. For some reason there is problem with the `title` attributte of the `a` tag(' games' isn't concatenated). For example if I have `$gameCategorie = '3D'` I get `<a title='3D'>3D games</a>` I want to get `<a title='3D games'>3D games</a>`

```
foreach($gamesCategories as $gamesCategorie){
        $gameContent = $gamesCategorie.' games';
        echo '<li><a title='.$gameContent.'>';
        echo $gameContent;
        echo '</a></li>'. PHP_EOL; 
        }
```

Ideas about improving the quality of the code and tutorials about HTML generation by PHP are also appreciated.

Comment: a title doesn't get proper value as $gameContent variable

Comment: "Doesn't get proper value" is never a good description of a programming problem. What *exactly* goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All valid xhtml should have attributes enclosed in speachmarks. Try this

```
foreach($gamesCategories as $gamesCategorie){
     $gameContent = $gamesCategorie.' games';
     echo '<li><a title="'.$gameContent.'">';
     echo $gameContent;         
     echo '</a></li>'. PHP_EOL;          
}
```

Comment: Even this will solve too! and easy : echo "<li><a title=$gameContent>"; [ :) ]

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow - No that wouldn't solve it. `$gameContent` contains a space and without quotes would only display the first word for the tile.